# c# method first run is slower than after first run

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made this code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class InstanceTest : MonoBehaviour { 
public int cnt; public bool startTest1 = false; public bool startTest2 = false;

 void Update()
 {
     if (startTest1)
         Test1(cnt);
     if (startTest2)
         Test2(cnt);
 }
 void Test1(int cnt)
 {
     float a;
     for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)        
         a = 1f + 1f;        
 }
 static void Test2(int cnt)
 {
     float a;
     for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)        
         a = 1f + 1f;        
 }
}
```

On Profiler

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLCHh.jpg)

why CPU Time on Update() hiccup when call Test1() and Test2() at first time?

Comment: What makes you think it is slower the first time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why subsequent direct method call is much faster than the first call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417598/why-subsequent-direct-method-call-is-much-faster-than-the-first-call)

Comment: @mjwills I used RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod() like link's answer but still have hiccup...

Answer (score 2):

There's probably some JIT (Just In Time) compilation happening during the first call of the functions.

The second and subsequent times the functions are called, there's an optimized version of them waiting.

Comment: @minkyuPark You may find https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/performance-optimization/optimizing-scripts-unity-games of interest.